# Getting rid of the last space

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm unsure how to get rid of the last space, could anyone show me what to do to my code to do so please.
Thanks

```
class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        item = self.head 
        print("[", end="")
        while item != None:
            print(item.get_data(), sep="", end=" ")
            item = item.get_next()
        print("]", end="")

    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node
```

Expected: [8 7 6 3 5]

Got: [8 7 6 3 5 ]

Comment: Please don't use images, just copy the code into the question.

Comment: `__str__` should not `print`, it should be constructing and `return`-ing a `str`.  I'd strongly recommend implementing a `__iter__` method first, then implementing `__str__` in terms of it (you could basically implement `__str__` as `return '[{}]'.format(' '.join(map(str, self)))` if you had a functioning `__iter__`, which you need for a proper sequence anyway).

Comment: If you want to keep the loop, just add an `if` in there that tests whether you're on the last element, and, if so, changes the `end` parameter to the empty string.

Comment: When constructing the string u can just iterate until `item.get_next()` is None. Then it will exit the loop when item is pointing to the last node and u can add the data without a space in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The exception said `__str__ returned non-string`. Because you print the representation instead of return it. And you can use `join` function to concate items in list with a separator.

```
def __str__(self):
    item = self.head

    items = list()

    while item:
       items.append(str(item.get_data()))
       item = item.get_next()    

   return '[' + ' '.join(items) + ']'
```

Comment: HI, this is the error I got from above code: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Node found

Comment: Thank you so much it works!!! Is there anyway I can add you or chat you on this for future problems??